# how to solve about out-file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script it was working (i am using windows10 64bit)
but suddenly it stopped.

Here is my script:

```
Try{
error.clear();
write-host "After Clear Error"; 
write-host "Location is:  -nonewline; 
(get-location).Path 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SqClient"); 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO"); 
Write-host "After setting systems for forms"; 
[string] $CRLF = "`r`n" 
[string] $fileName = "civ_" + (get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + " .txt";
Write-host "File Name is:  $fileName";
[string] $outputFile = ("C:\temp\" + $fileName); 
write-host "outputfiIe is:  SoutputFiIe"; 
[string] $newLocation = "G:\Teams\Data\support\"; 
Write-host "After setting FILE information"; 
($CRLF + "Script Run Commencing at " + (get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.fff")) | out-file $outputFile -append -encoding ASCII; 
write-host "After WRITING INFORMATION TO FILE';
```

The error message is

> out-file: Couldnot find file 'C:\temp\civ_20230224_105513.txt'
> [image]

I have checked several times, not sure where did it go wrong.

So I turn to the almighty community.

Thank you

Comment: use sysinternals procmon to see exactly what file io is being performed and what the responses were

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that your code above is riddled with syntactical errors, .e.g. quotes that are mismatched and arguments within quotes that should be outside them. You are also trying to load assemblies with outdated methods and incorrect assembly names or at least ones I didn't have loaded so I commented them out.

Here is a working version which you can use to compare the differences with.

```
Clear-Host

$error.clear()
write-host "After Clear Error" 
write-host "Location is: $((get-location).Path)"

Add-Type -assemblyname "System.Windows.Forms"
#Next two comment out can't find assembly tripping the missing Catch?
#Add-Type -assemblyname "System.Data.SqClient"
#Add-Type -assemblyname "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO"

Write-host "After setting systems for forms" 

$fileName = "civ_" + $((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")) + ".txt"
Write-host "File Name is:  $fileName"
$outputFile =$(Join-Path -path  "C:\temp" -ChildPath "$fileName")
write-host "outputfiIe is:  $outputFile" 
$newLocation = "G:\Teams\Data\support\" 
Write-host "After setting FILE information" 
$("`n$CRLF Script Run Commencing at $((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.fff"))") | 
    out-file $outputFile -append -encoding ASCII 

write-host "After WRITING INFORMATION TO FILE"
```

Here's the Screen Output:

```
After Clear Error
Location is: G:\BEKDocs\Scripts
After setting systems for forms
File Name is:  civ_20230223_210905.txt
outputfiIe is:  C:\temp\civ_20230223_210905.txt
After setting FILE information
After WRITING INFORMATION TO FILE
```

Here's the file content:

```
 Script Run Commencing at 20230223_21:09:05.208
```

If you are not using a tool like the ISE or Visual Code you should be as they would have caught a lot of your problems.

I hope this helps you along your PowerShell journey.